# Problem connecting to the salesforce authentication service when trying to authorize an org

Tags: oauth2, salesforcedx-cli

Problem connecting to the salesforce authentication service when trying to authorize an org.

Getting below error:

Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange. Due to: request to https://somecomnay--preprod.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo failed, reason: Socket connection timeout

This is most likely not an error with the Salesforce CLI. Please ensure all information is accurate and try again.

I have tried revoking all access to sfdx cli in my account also. [image]

Comment: I had this same issue today and then it resolved itself shortly after when I tried again.